# Change line type in gpplot in R

Tags: r, visualization

Context: I have two variables under emotion_dict that I am graphing in the same line graph.

Problem: However when I change the linetype in geom_line, it changes the appearance of both variables.

Question: Does anyone know how to alter the code below to keep the line types separate and display a key? I have done this before only with the ggline function, but that is not appropriate here.

See attached file and code below for more context:[image]

```
posneg_plot2 <- d_posneg %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=year, y=rel_freq, group=emotion_dict, colour=emotion_dict)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1, size=0.7, linetype=2, colour="black") +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x="Year", y="Positive and Negative Sentiment (%)") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1970,2017,2)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  scale_color_hue(labels = c("Negative Sentiment", "Positive Sentiment")) +
  labs(colour = "LIWC Dictionaries") + theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=17))
  #stat_cor(, method = "pearson", p.accuracy = 0.001, r.accuracy = 00.01, size = 4.5, colour = "black")
```

---

EDIT: Answer below and now attempting to change the labels within the group accordingly: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply specify the field to be used for the linetype for the `linetype` argument within an `aes` mapping as follows:

```
posneg_plot2 <- d_posneg %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=year, y=rel_freq, group=emotion_dict, colour=emotion_dict)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=emotion_dict), alpha = 1, size=0.7, colour="black")
```

Comment: Thank you @Oxbowerce! Would you know why/ how to change the label names? I am trying the below but it hasn't yet changed the labels:

```{r}
  labs(color = "LIWC Dictionaries") +
  scale_color_hue(labels = c("Negative Sentiment", "Positive Sentiment")) +
```

I've also attached a new photo in the above comment.

Comment: Which labels do you exactly mean? The labels in the legend or do you want to add labels next to the lines?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear @Oxbowerce! I mean the labels for the legend that is shown underneath "Year": emotion_dict negemo and posemo

Comment: I think using `scale_linetype_manual(labels=c("Negative Sentiment", "Positive Sentiment"))` should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm, I added it and this error arises: "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 0 provided. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."

Comment: Despite this code chunk (some irrelevant lines removed):

```{r}
p2 <- d %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x=year, y=rel_freq, group=emotion_dict)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=emotion_dict), alpha = 1, size=0.7, colour="black") +
  labs(x="Year", y="Affective Positivity and Negatvitiy (%)") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_linetype_manual(labels = c("Affective Negativity", "Affective Positivity")) +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Times New Roman", size=17)) +
  labs(color = "LIWC Dictionaries") 
print(p2)
```